# Android JNI callback seems to call a random method

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface

I'm experiencing a very strange bug, which I'm thinking might be an environment issue, but I'd like to know if anyone else here is experiencing something similar.

First of all, up until now, everything worked perfectly.

I have a project which works with a [jni](/questions/tagged/jni) interface.

Here's the call from my [java](/questions/tagged/java) code:

```
myJniWrapper.load(CallbackActivity.this); // this code is inside a Runnable
```

Here's the load method:

```
public void load(Activity activityCalledFrom) {
        if (mLoaded == false) {
            loadNative(mNativeHandle, activityCalledFrom); // This is being called correctly.
        }
    }

private native void loadNative(long nativeHandle, Object activityCalledFrom);
```

Here's the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_datalogics_dlreader_jni_RMBook_loadNative
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong handle, jobject activityCalledFrom)
{
        if (handle)
        {
                jmethodID meth = NULL;

                // Convert the long back into a pointer
                RMBookNative *theBook = (RMBookNative *) handle;

                // Ensure the pointer is valid
                if (theBook != NULL)
                {
                        // Get the activity that we were called from
                        theBook->libraryActivityObj = env->NewGlobalRef(activityCalledFrom);

                        // Call loadDocument to set the URL for the dpdoc::Document
                        theBook->loadDocument();
                }
        }
}
```

Later on, once the loading is finished, the following code is called in the C++ code:

```
if (libraryActivityObj != NULL)
        {
                // Find the loadingFinished method on the library class
                meth = jenv->GetMethodID(libraryActivityCls, "loadingFinished", "()V");

                // Call the method on the activity
                jenv->CallVoidMethod(libraryActivityObj, meth);
        }
```

Then, back in the same activity, I have the following method:

```
public void loadingFinished() 
    {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "loading finished");
        doStuff();
    }
```

The strange thing is, everything is working (at least according to the logs) - and when the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tries to call the loadingFinished() method, it instead invokes some random public method in the activity I'm sending - or to be precise, it will call the same random method every time, but if I add another method in the activity, a different method will be called by the tag[:C++] code. It seems to randomly choose a method to call based on the total amount of methods in the activity.

I have tried: cleaning & rebuilding, restarting [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), restarting my Mac, restarting the device - nothing helps.

I do not understand what is happening and was hoping if anyone had any insight.

Please let me know if you need me to post more code / general info.

Comment: Where are you getting the libraryActivityClass from?  And if its being cached in C, are you updating the global ref count so the reference isn't freed?

Comment: Also, you're upping the global ref count of an Activity-  dangerous!  If you're recreated due to a configuration change, you'll refer to the wrong object.  And if you don't decrement the reference count correctly you'll have a major memory leak.  That's pretty much something you should never do on an Activity

Comment: Thanks! you were right about the class. It's since been changed to a different class and now It's going to be a headache to change everything accordingly. Post this suggestion as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.